# Checking What Entity is Being Updated on SavingChanges

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have a handler that causes a sub context_SaviningChanges to be executed when an update is made to one of the entity objects like so:

```
AddHandler Me.SavingChanges, AddressOf context_SavingChanges
```

I want to have specific code executed for each entity that is being updated. So, if it is a "phone" entity I want to trigger one piece of code but if it is a "buildings" entity I want to trigger another piece of code. In pseudo code I want to do something like this:

```
For Each entry as ObjectStateEntry in DirectCast(sender, ObjectContext).ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Modified)
   If entry.entity("phone") Then
       ... code goes here for phone changes ...
   ElseIf entry.entity("building")
       ... code goes here for building changes ...
   Else
       ... code goes here for other entity changes ...
Next
```

Comment: You can't do entry.entity("phone") - so i need to know how to correctly check the currently edited entity, so i can set appropriate code for that specific entity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check for the type of the [ObjectStateEntry.Entity [msdn]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectstateentry.entity.aspx):

```
If TypeOf entry.Entity Is Phone Then
  ' ...
End If
```